# Where does the Green Goblin's mask come from?

Tags: character, spider-man-trilogy

So, it's been years since I've actually sat down and watched Spider-Man, the Toby Maguire film, and I got to thinking... Do they ever actually show where Norman's mask comes from? I remember where he gets the suit from, but not the mask.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**We don't know**.

At least I don't think it's ever revealed. He obviously took the Goblin suit from Oscorp and discarded the *original* helmet in favour of the new, scary, goblin one - but to my knowledge it's never shown *where* he got this helmet from.

Comment: I know he had the mask out in the house at multiple points.  I could've sworn I saw other masks, too - like it was part of an art collection or something.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse: I recall something similar. I think when he goes into his little secret place, they are lining the walls or something - but we never see _where_ he gets them from.

Comment: No, I meant different styles of masks - like something that belonged to African tribesmen, etc.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse: No I got what you meant. He had a few masks (of which the goblin mask could have been one). It did look like a collection. I just meant that, unlike the suit which we _know_ came from Oscorp, we don't know about the masks, that was all.